# How do I add some padding between the search field and the first navigation item of my sidebar?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I've got a pretty simple `NavigationSplitView` set up like so:

```swift
NavigationSplitView(sidebar: {
  List {
    ForEach(viewModel.pages) { page in
      NavigationLink(page.name, tag: page.id, selection: $viewModel.selectedId) {
        Text(page.name)
          .navigationTitle(page.name)
      }
    }
  }
}, detail: {
  Text(viewModel.selectedPage?.name ?? "")
}).searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .sidebar).navigationTitle(viewModel.selectedPage?.name ?? "Buttons")
```

Which results in the following UI:

[image]

How do I add some padding between the search field and the first `NavigationLink`item in my sidebar? It looks pretty squished, and Apple's apps that place search fields in the sidebar all seem to have some padding there.

Reference screenshots:

#### App Store

[image]

#### Books

[image]

#### Messages

[image]

#### Maps

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem by wrapping `Section` around the `ForEach` structure:

```swift
NavigationSplitView {
    List {
        Section {
            ForEach(viewModel.pages) { page in
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
} detail: {
    // ...
}
```

- Screenshot without `Section`: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Figa.png).
- Screenshot with `Section`: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM2ha.png).

I do not know whether that is the "recommended" way of solving that problem.